# Android: ShareActionProvider with no history

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

According to the Android documentation if I don't want my ShareActionProvider to persist the share history I should call

```
mShareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(null)
```

However when I do this I get the following crash on selecting a share option:

```
11-15 10:06:34.848: E/AndroidRuntime(22461): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No preceding call to #readHistoricalData
11-15 10:06:34.848: E/AndroidRuntime(22461):    at android.widget.ActivityChooserModel.persistHistoricalDataIfNeeded(ActivityChooserModel.java:573)
11-15 10:06:34.848: E/AndroidRuntime(22461):    at android.widget.ActivityChooserModel.addHisoricalRecord(ActivityChooserModel.java:743)
11-15 10:06:34.848: E/AndroidRuntime(22461):    at android.widget.ActivityChooserModel.chooseActivity(ActivityChooserModel.java:491)
11-15 10:06:34.848: E/AndroidRuntime(22461):    at android.widget.ActivityChooserView$Callbacks.onItemClick(ActivityChooserView.java:547)
```

Here is the code that sets up the ShareActionProvider:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.article_pager_menu, menu);
    // mShareActionProvider is a field in the Activity
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share)
            .getActionProvider();
    mShareActionProvider
            .setShareHistoryFileName(null);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    mShareActionProvider.onCreateActionView();
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So in the end I had to write my own ShareActionProvider by copying the one found in Android source. I also had to copy over the ActivityChooserView and the ActivityChooserModel from source. The actual modification needed to hide the default activity in the action bar is in the updateAppearance() method in the ActivityChooserView. This is how it should look:

```
private void updateAppearance() {
    // Expand overflow button.
    if (mAdapter.getCount() > 0) {
        mExpandActivityOverflowButton.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        mExpandActivityOverflowButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
    mDefaultActivityButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (mDefaultActivityButton.getVisibility() == VISIBLE) {
        mActivityChooserContent.setBackgroundDrawable(mActivityChooserContentBackground);
    } else {
        mActivityChooserContent.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }
}
```

I couldn't figure out why setShareHistoryFileName(null) was causing the problem I originally described though. Thanks for the attempted answer Seven.

Comment: How did you extent the `ActivityChooserModel` which is a Singleton?

Comment: works like a charm, just don't forget to change the necessary import in these files

Comment: Excellent! I've been messing around with this for a while now, this works perfectly.

Comment: @AmerHadi An instance of ActivityChooserViewAdapter within the ActivityChooserView class.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the source code on ActivityChooserModel I've found that the history file is open using Context's openFileInput. As long as that class keep working like that, you will be able to keep your history "clean" if you delete it using the usual method for those kinds of files:

```
getApplicationContext().deleteFile(SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
shareActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
```

The "most used" icon **will** show for a while, when the selected application is opening, but as soon as the user is back at your app, it will disappear.

You could also delete the file on your onShareTargetSelected method, if needed.

Comment: weird, but not work, even what deleteFile returns true. As I've answered above, use random file name to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I tried all, I'm using old widget.ShareActionProvider (not compat 7), so null leads to crash, deleteFile surely deletes but history always still exists after app restart... so I've found only one working thing: random!

```
    String fname=ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME;
    try {
        fname = prefs.getString("SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME", ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
        getApplicationContext().deleteFile(ShareActionProvider.DEFAULT_SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME);
        fname="SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME"+Math.random()*1000;
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
        ed.putString("SHARE_HISTORY_FILE_NAME", fname);
        ed.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"err "+e.toString());
    }
    mSharedActionProvider.setShareHistoryFileName(fname);
```

Answer (score -1):

modified com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider's onCreateActionView then call ActivityChooserModel's method: setHistoryMaxSize(0)

Comment: The OP is not talking about action bar sherlock usage.