# ShareActionProvider icon in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I have implemented the share icon in the actionbar. After you press on it, and then pick which source you want to share it to, the icon widens and shows the last source you shared with.

[image: twitter]

I don't want the second icon to pop up after they select a source.
How do I stop the second icon from appearing?

Answer (score 2):

Fork `ShareActionProvider` and get rid of it. There's no option to control this behavior. As [another SO person has discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17931240/115145), forking `ShareActionProvider` is tedious.